# Safari Unicode issue with web font "Entypo"

Tags: unicode, safari, webfonts

I'm using a pictograph web font called Entypo made by Daniel Bruce for a project, which does not work properly in Safari 5 for Windows. Yet the font works fine for Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Opera.

Here's the [character map](http://www.entypo.com/characters/). Open the link in Safari and you'll see missing pictographs. It seems like the unicode codes with 5 characters or more are throwing off Safari. Any idea why?

Comment: I can confirm that the problem exists in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7. Most of the special characters look ok, but some of them are missing completely, such as the first two, U+1F4DE and U+1F4F1. For comparison, my test page for Plane 1 characters http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/code2001.html does not display well in Safari, on a system that has Code2001 font installed and where other browsers display the characters. So it seems to be some issue that Safari has with characters beyond BMP (i.e. with code numbers > FFFF hex.).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Interesting. Thanks for the input. I wonder why Safari is hitting a snag processing characters beyond BMP.

Answer (score 0):

check this out.

http://www.open-logix.com/webtech/use-custom-webfontspictograms-in-5-steps/

I did some test with lots of browsers and even the different types of elements. Try testing it with span,div, and many other ones to see if there is a most compatible element tag.

There are issues on different browsers outside of safari as well, so don't be discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://github.com/danielbruce/entypo/issues/14#issuecomment-19171286

I think this should "solve" your problem.